# Some of my application initializers don't seem to trigger?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I have a top level application called `SearchApp` which has a sub-app called `TeamApp`. The files are structured like this:

```
search_app.js.coffee # The top-level application.
team_app/
  app.js.coffee
  team_list.js.coffee
  team_invite.js.coffee
```

I initialize my application in `search_app.js.coffee`:

```
window.Domainer = {}

# This is the top level application.
Domainer.SearchApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application()

# Assign a region to the Application.
Domainer.SearchApp.addRegions(stage: '#stage')
```

And start it in the html view:

```
<script>Domainer.SearchApp.start({});</script>
```

The Submodule `TeamApp` is laid out over a few files (below). THe problem is that some of the files in the `TeamApp` module don't seem to be able to add initializers to the `SearchApp`. This is evidenced by the fact that I can `console.log` from the initialization in one file but not in the other.

```
# team_app/app.js.coffee
Domainer.SearchApp.module "TeamApp", (TeamApp, SearchApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  # Initializers
  # ----------

  SearchApp.addInitializer (options) ->
    console.log "This will log when I call Domainer.SearchApp.start()"

  # In coffeescript it's important to explicitly return.
  return TeamApp

# team_app/team_list.js.coffee
Domainer.SearchApp.module "TeamApp", (TeamApp, SearchApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class CompactSearcher extends Marionette.ItemView
    # ... various code relating to this view.

  class TeamList extends Marionette.CollectionView
    # various code relating to this view.

  SearchApp.addInitializer (options) ->
    console.log "This will never log for some reason."

  return TeamApp

# team_app/invite_view.js.coffee
Domainer.SearchApp.module "TeamApp", (TeamApp, SearchApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class InviteView extends Marionette.ItemView
    # ... various code relating to this view.

  SearchApp.addInitializer (options) ->
    console.log "This will never log either."

  return TeamApp
```

Is it not possible to split one module across multiple files? That's the only thing that I can think is happening here. What else could be causing the problem?

Comment: Is it common to split the same module across files? kind of seems like it would be different modules to me. If i were doing this, i would use sub-modules: TeamApp, TeamApp.Search, TeamApp.Invite as examples. I'd love to hear your thoughts on why you want the same module in multiple files, though. open an issue on the github probject, if you don't mind: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/issues

Comment: Done. https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/issues/107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> Is it not possible to split one module across multiple files?

Checking the [backbone-marionette source](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js#L705) confirms that this is exactly what's going on:

```
// Get the module name, and check if it exists on
// the current parent already
moduleName = moduleNames[i];
module = parentModule[moduleName];

if (!module){ 
  // This is where the module definition is used...
}

return module;
```

So if you try to define the same module multiple times, only the first definition will be used.

Answer (score 2):

FYI - I've updated Marionette to support this scenario now.

```
MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

MyApp.module("Foo", function(Foo){
  Foo.def1 = true;
});

MyApp.module("Foo", function(Foo){
  Foo.def2 = true;
});

MyApp.Foo.def1; //=> true
MyApp.Foo.def2; //=> true
```